# How do I make two cells dependent on one another without circular error?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

In Excel 2013, I have cells A1, A2, and A3 along with B1, B2, and B3. Column A is a yearly calculation and Column B is a weekly calculation.

For example, if the user updates A1 (e.g., `5200`), I want to auto-update B1 (e.g., `100`). If the user updates B1 (e.g., `50`), I want to auto-update A1 (e.g., `2600`). Likewise for A2-B2 and A3-B3.

When I try to monitor both, it creates a circular issue and Excel crashes.

Comment: Put the values into hidden columns and use THOSE for reference and math instead.  Just have your fields that people can see echo the result.

Comment: Use an event-triggered VBA macro.  If you have a problem with the code, post back with what you have and outline the problems you have run into.

Comment: Are people updating A1 itself? Typing "5200" over top of an existing formula? Or they update elsewhere, and the affect is shown in A1?

Comment: Forumulas can exist elsewhere in hidden cells if needed. I have the data on another worksheet.

Comment: I want to use an event-triggered VBA macro like Change_Worksheet, but I simply cannot figure out how to do it without creating a circular issue.

Comment: If a sub enters data in your field, there is no formula, there will not be circular references unless your instructions contain a major fallacy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use formula at all then. Use a `_Change` event like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False  'Prevent infinite looping

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    'User has changed something in column A:
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target / 52
Else
    'User has changed something in column B:
    Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target * 52
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```